# How to include a photo into moderncv?

Tags: moderncv

I'm currently using this lines of code to display my personal informations using moderncv:

```
\firstname{x}
\familyname{xx}
\title{xxx}              
\address{xxx}{xxx}    
\email{xxx}
\mobile{+xxx} 
\extrainfo{xxx}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{xx.jpg}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\personaltitle{%
  \def\phonesdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
    \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
 \par\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
     {\LARGE\textbf{\@firstname\ \@lastname}} \\
     \@addressstreet \\
     \@addresscity  \\
     \@extrainfo \\
     \mobilephonesymbol:\ \collection@phones@item  \\
     \emailsymbol:\ \emaillink{\@email} \\
 \end{tabular}\par%\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\par%
}
```

But adding the `\photo...` line doesn't display the photo in the top-right. How do I please to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Could you please complete your code so it can be compiled? That is, add `\documentclass{}`, any necessary packages and `\begin{document}... \end{document}`.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154383/how-to-include-picture-in-banking-style-with-exactly-position and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148192/adding-pictures-to-moderncv

Comment: @cfr, yeah it compiles.

Comment: @touhami, when I add that `\photo...` line, the photo doesn't appear. I think that's because of the redefined `personaltitle`. But I don't know how to fix it. Any brilliant suggestion, please?

Comment: if you use style banking there is no photo by default

Comment: But it will not compile for us! That is, if we copy-paste the code, it will not compile because it is not a complete document.